# How to decode a UTF-16BE CSV file in Golang

Tags: csv, go, decode, utf-16

I'm trying to decode CSV files encoded in UTF-16BE in Golang. What is the charmap ISO character number that I have to call for the new reader ?

I want to invoke

```
csv.NewReader(charmap.XXXX.NewDecoder().Reader(file))
```

What should be the value of XXXX ?

Comment: None of them, as clearly indicated in the `charmap` docs: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap

Comment: If you want to decode utf-16, you'd use https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf16/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding/unicode#UTF16

```
unicode.UTF16(BigEndian, UseBOM)
```

Answer (score 0):

After some review, a simple way to decode UTF16 into UTF8 is provided by this code:

https://gist.github.com/bradleypeabody/185b1d7ed6c0c2ab6cec#file-gistfile1-go

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`golang.org/x/text/encoding/unicode.UTF16`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding/unicode#UTF16) to create a decoder from your target UTF-16 Little/Big-Endian encoding into UTF-8.

The code below shows a working example for UTF-16 LE ([Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/uEl3-23dO4g)):

```
dec := unicode.UTF16(unicode.LittleEndian, unicode.UseBOM).NewDecoder()
utf16r := getUTF16LittleEndianCSVReader()
utf8r := transform.NewReader(utf16r, dec)

csvr := csv.NewReader(utf8r)
records, err := csvr.ReadAll()
// TODO: handle err

fmt.Printf("%#v", records)
// [][]string{[]string{"id", "name"}, []string{"1", "foo"}}
```

Switching to Big-endian should be as simple as below:

```
enc := unicode.UTF16(unicode.BigEndian, unicode.UseBOM).NewDecoder()
```